# Output parameters of array objects to a string

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int MaxStudents = 4;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     Student[] studentList;
     studentList = new Student[4];

     studentList[0] = new Student(51584, 17);
     studentList[1] = new Student(51585, 19);
     studentList[2] = new Student(51586, 15);
     studentList[3] = new Student(51587, 20);

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxStudents; i++)
        {
            lstStudents.Items.Add(studentList.ToString()[i]);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: In the Student class I have:

```
public Student(int id, int age) {
this.id = id;
this.age = age;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("ID: {0} - Age: {1}", this.id, this.age);
}
```

Then in the form load I have:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Student[] studentList;
studentList = new Student[4];

studentList[0] = new Student(51584, 17);
studentList[1] = new Student(51585, 19);
studentList[2] = new Student(51586, 15);
studentList[3] = new Student(51587, 20);

lstStudents.Items.AddRange(studentList);
}
```

I was wondering how I would output the parameters of each object in the array to the listbox. How would I make it so that each object is displayed in the listbox like so:

ID: 51584 - Age: 17

I'm not too sure how to basically convert the parameters into plain text to be listed in the listbox whilst adding additional text before the parameters (Like I did with 'id:', the hyphen and 'Age:')

Sorry for the long winded question but thought I'd explain as best as I can.

Comment: @Jonesy Pasted the wrong code in. Basically I want to be able to take integers from the parentheses and be able to output them as items in the listbox. I assume I'd have to convert them to a string or something along those lines but I want to be able to add text before or after the text i.e. so I can output `ID: 51584` rather than just the number itself.

Comment: Check my answer, which will solve all your issues

Comment: @T.S. I think overriding `ToString` is the right way to go about it but it's getting it to work as intended that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Overriding string is NOT a way for this. Overriding string is done for more complex issues, outside of scope of this. My code is 4 lines that solve your entire problem, appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a close look at this line:

```
lstStudents.Items.Add(studentList.ToString()[i]);
```

You write `studentList.ToString()[i]`. This means you call `ToString` on `studentList` instead of the students. It should be `lstStudents.Items.Add(studentList[i].ToString())` (with the indexer `[i]` placed behind `studentList`).

Assuming that you have overwritten `ToString` in the `Student` class you can add all students in a single call:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Student[] studentList;
    studentList = new Student[4];

    studentList[0] = new Student(51584, 17);
    studentList[1] = new Student(51585, 19);
    studentList[2] = new Student(51586, 15);
    studentList[3] = new Student(51587, 20);

    lstStudents.Items.AddRange(studentList);
}
```

Comment: See my edit. I've overridden `ToString` in the `Student` class but it's not outputting anything to the list box

Comment: Your updated code should work. Are you sure that Form1_Load is called?

Comment: It must handle the `Load` event. See the events in the properties window of Form1.

Comment: D'oh! I miss the most obvious things sometimes! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Student` to be shown that way anytime you want a string value, the easiest way is to override `ToString`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Name: {0} - Age: {1}", this.Name, this.Age);
}
```

Then you can just do

```
lstStudents.Items.Add(studentList[i]);
```

The benefit of adding an *object* instead of a *string* is that the `SelectedItem` property of the listbox will be the object instead of just the string representation.

Or you can format the string that's sent to the listbox:

```
lstStudents.Items.Add(string.Format("Name: {0} - Age: {1}", studentList[i].Name, studentList[i].Age));
```

Comment: Additionally, the OP has to use `studentList[i].ToString()` in his code instead of "studentList.ToString()[i]".

Comment: @D Stanley so would this apply to integers as well? Like in my updated post could I do `return string.Format("ID: {0} - Age: {1}", this.ID, this.Age); to output the integers? I assume you can?

Comment: @user2929108 Yes `string.Format` will accept integers as well.  It can accept any object in fact.

Comment: Yes, you can use integers as well.

Comment: @DStanley I've put the override into `Student.cs` and the listbox code itself is in `Form1.cs` in the FormLoad event but it's not outputting anything into the listbox. Do I have the code in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Class student - create property
public string Display
{
   get { return string.Format("ID: {0} - Age: {1}", this.ID, this.Age); }
} 

 // In the form class - set listbox
 lstStudents.Datasource = StudentArray;
 lstStudents.DisplayMember = "Display";
 lstStudents.ValueMember = "ID";

 // The benefit of this is that later you can do this
 Student s = (Student)lstStudents.SelectedItem
 // Now you have access to full student info
```